# How would I detect if a string is a block of code or not?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python script that will see if there is code in a string or not. this can not only be python code it can also be other code as seen in the picture below

Here is an example of what I need to process.

[image: example]

I know you could just just do a whole bunch of `if 'var =' in code`
but this can also be false triggered.

Is there a better way to detect stuff like this?

thanks, ira.

Comment: Yes, Also this can not only be python but can also be other languages like lua as seen in the picture